# Css: overflow: auto + specified width

Tags: css

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5VCfm/2/embedded/result/

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 20px
}
.container + .container {
    top: 260px;
}
.content-container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
.content-wrap {
    border: 1px solid navy;
}
.content {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="content">
                 <h2>No width</h2>
                large content see http://jsfiddle.net/5VCfm/2/embedded/result/
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <div class="content" style="width:300px">
                 <h2>Width 300px</h2>
                large content see http://jsfiddle.net/5VCfm/2/embedded/result/
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If width of element inside container is specified, he takes off the edge of the parent creating a horizontal scrolling. What is most characteristic behaves in Mozilla and Chrome. But Opera and IE show all right.
How to solve the problem? Is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The parent container has a `max-width:90%`, means it will become smaller as much as it can but it will never surpass 90% of the viewport width.

When this 90% is smaller than 300px (child), the horizontal scroll bar is being created, this process is completely normal, you just have to realize that the child has a fixed width, it will not get smaller.

Use `max-width:300px;` on the `.content`, this will allow it to have a 300px width IF IT CAN, but when the parent (90%) is less, it will become tighter.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PVKuJ/)

Comment: @WinBack I changed my answer.

Comment: max-width is good and it works, but what if I need a min-width. The first container has no width, and the width varies by content.

Comment: Use `min-width` on `.container` it will have a 90% max-width and for example, a 300px min-width.

Comment: Yes, I see that it works here, but it does not work in my case. Later, I reproduce my situation.